# Critique: WordPress Plugin Banner

Tags: website-design, typography, critique

I'd love some feedback on the banner I created for my WordPress plugin. This is the banner that displays when someone is on the plugin's page in the WordPress repository. You can [see it here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/swift-callouts/), if you like.

I want it to be simple and give the user an idea what the plugin does before they even read about it.

I originally had a version that was just the blue background with the callout box in the corner, but I decided adding some text would give the viewer a better idea what the plugin does.

I have zero graphic design skills and only GIMP to work with, so I can't get too extravagant.

Any feedback or advice would be appreciated.

[image: plugin banner]

---

A little more info on what I am looking for from a critique, as per comment request.

I mostly want to know if people feel like they get a sense about what the plugin does based on the image. I also want to know how I can make it look more professional. Since I'm not a graphic designer and have little skill, I don't really have the design sense, so I was hoping someone with design sense could help me out.

I also would like to know if the addition of the grey text outside the box is a good choice, or does it look too cluttered this way?

Here is what the ORIGINAL looked like, before I added the additional text.

[image]

Comment: Just remove all the trash around and put your title in white in the middle of background. Will be minimal, but at least not awful.

Comment: I undeleted this question because I felt the answer was  a good fit for someone in the future.  However, I am aware that the question does need some work to fit in our scope.  When I have more time later, if someone hasnt already, I will edit the question.

Comment: I deleted it because, while the answer was informative, it didn't answer my question. My question was about my banner and the answer was an evaluation of templates in the plugin, which are user modifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Is the pale shadow-treatment on the entire box on the WP page something that is added by WP?

Essentially what you are making is a "footnote" or "quote" functionality, boxes to add a little more information. Treat it as such: as something that should not scream loudly over the main content, but be a teaser. Consider what newspapers do: More information:

---

[image]

---

Quotes:

---

[image]

---

It is not obvious to me what the plugin does from the image. In context however, I suppose it makes sense, but that is dependant on two things:

- the user knowing what to look for, search results in WP
- or, that the user actually reads some of the text

Loose the shadow on the white box, it looks like it is from 1985. The black outline is a little funeral-y: you have contrast in colours, and it is unnecessarily dramatic.

How will this widget look in my blog? Is the image close to that?

I do not know how it is supposed to look or work, but if you are going to use the header image as a "preview" or taste or teaser, you must either:

- make the header image show what the result of the plugin are

or better:

- use some visuals to try to get the message across and a real-life example with text.

I had a look at your screenshots of the widget in action, and *loose the shadow* or make it very very soft. This looks dated, and you have plenty of contrast going on there.

[image]

It interferes with the text, it looks dated, and it takes way too much attention away from the main content. Asides like that can be easily worked with a little whitespace and a contrasting font/italic.

Here are two simple mockups that demonstrates what I am trying to say. Keep it simple. Use few effects (you will have to forgive my crude examples, but i figure you get the point).

You do not really need the box:

[image]

If you *really want* the box, keep it as simple as possible. If you *really* want the shadow, keep it *away* from the text, or at least allow a good chunk of whitespace.

[image]